# Can not get TensorFlow working on mac for python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a from scratch AI model but its becoming to cumbersome to make improvements by hand and I would like to do the model in tensor flow instead in order to make it easier to modify. To do this I need to get TF working but when I install it I keep getting an error when importing it. It is as follows:
"Could not import tensorflow. Do not import tensorflow from its source directory; change directory to outside the TensorFlow source tree, and relaunch your Python interpreter from there."

I am using Pip3 and python 3 on mac so please if you have any idea whats wrong please help.

Comment: is that the entire error you're getting or is there some sort of a path given?

Comment: Are you running Python from/inside the source directory of tensorflow?(installed directory of tensorflow). Run Python outside the directory of tensorflow.